# A basic doubt on a infinite series problem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I see in Rudin the following statement is claimed for the following convergent series:

$$1-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6} + \dots$$

If $s$ is the sum of this series then $$s \lt 1 -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}$$. How is that possible to tell without knowing $s$ ?

Answer (score 2):

$$S_{2k+1} = 1-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5}\right) - \ldots -\left(\frac{1}{2k} - \frac{1}{2k+1}\right)  < 1-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}-\left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5}\right)$$ and $S_{2k+1}\to s$ imply
$$s \leqslant 1-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}-\left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5}\right) < 1-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: I could not follow the argument. If some particular partial sums are bounded by a constant, why should the limit be bounded by that constant?

Comment: You used the expression "convergent series" in your question, so I assumed that you already know that it converges. Then just consider the sequence $S_{2k+1}$ which converges to the same limit.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known fact: suppose you have a decreasing sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$  of positive numbers and that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$. Then the series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n a_n
$$
converges to some number $s$ and the following holds for any natural number $k$:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{2k+1}a_n < s < \sum_{n=0}^{2k} a_n
$$

Let's prove, by induction on $k$, that the sequence $(s_{2k+1})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is increasing and that $(s_{2k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is decreasing, where
$$
s_k=\sum_{n=0}^k (-1)^n a_n.
$$
Indeed
$$
s_{2k+3}-s_{2k+1}=-a_{2k+3}+a_{2k}>0
$$
and
$$
s_{2k+2}-s_{2k}=a_{2k+2}-a_{2k+1}<0.
$$
Therefore, if the alternating series converges to $s$ we must have the inequality above, because
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}s_{2k+1}=s=\lim_{k\to\infty}s_{2k}.
$$

The fact that the alternating sequence converges stems from the fact that
$$
s_{2k+2}-s_{2k+1}=a_{2k+2}
$$
and so we can make this difference as small as we want, since the sequence $(a_n)$ converges to zero by hypothesis.

Comment: hmm, this is the application of a theorem in Rudin $\sum {a_nb_n}$ converges.

Comment: Is the inequality after the line "for any natural number $k$" correct ? all the $a_n$s are positive. Then how can the quantity at the left of $s$ be lower than the quantity at the right ?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$ 1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\left( \frac{1}{4}-\dots \right)=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-a< 1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}$$

Since $a>0$.

**Note:**

$$a=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\dots.$$